# Adding Items to datagridview with Excel database

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, oledb

I'm trying to add items in my datagridview by using vb.net code. I'm using an Excel database. Here's my code and all the things that I've tried are in the form of comments.I would really appreciate it if someone call help me. I've been trying it the whole of this week. Thanks

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.DataTable
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Welcome
Private Sub ImportExceldata(DataExcelFile As String, ImportData As DataGridView)



    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(0) Then
        Try
            Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim dataSet As System.Data.DataSet
            Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & DataExcelFile & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
            MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [CandidatesCallCenterLocation$]", MyConnection)
            'MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Attendace")
            dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
            MyCommand.Fill(dataSet)
            ImportData.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
            DataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)


            MyConnection.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try

    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(1) Then
        Try
            Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim dataSet As System.Data.DataSet
            Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & DataExcelFile & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
            MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [ExpectedNumberofCalls$]", MyConnection)
            'MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Attendace")
            dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
            MyCommand.Fill(dataSet)
            ImportData.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
            DataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
            MyConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(2) Then
        Try
            Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim dataSet As System.Data.DataSet
            Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & DataExcelFile & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
            MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [CostProcessingTelephoneCalls$]", MyConnection)
            'MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Attendace")
            dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
            MyCommand.Fill(dataSet)
            ImportData.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
            DataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
            MyConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    ImportExceldata("C:\Users\Home\Desktop\dss.xlsx", DataGridView)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView.SelectedRows
        DataGridView.Rows.Remove(row)

    Next
End Sub
```

This part consists off the add button and all the codes that I've tried. I thought the bottom part worked but apparently, it doesn't.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click



    ' Dim Table As New DataTable("Table")
    ' Table.Columns.Add("Area Code", Type.GetType("System.Int64"))
    ' Table.Columns.Add("Metropolitan Area", Type.GetType("System.Int64"))
    'Table.Columns.Add("Annual Fixed Cost", Type.GetType("System.Int64"))
    'Table.Columns.Add("Wage per hour", Type.GetType("System.Int64"))
    'Table.Rows.Add("", "", "", "")
    'Table.Rows.Add(2, "aaaa", "bbbb", 33)
    'Table.Rows.Add(3, "cccc", "dddd", 53)
    'Table.Rows.Add(4, "eeee", "ffff", 63)
    'Table.Rows.Add(5, "rrrr", "qqqq", 73)
    'Table.Rows.Add(6, "gggg", "hhhh", 83)
    ' Dim Add As Object
    ' Add = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ' Dim oneadd As Excel.Workbook
    ' Dim sheetadd As Excel.Worksheet
    'Dim fexcel As String = "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\dss.xlsx"
    ' Dim curLine As Integer = 0

    'oneadd = Add.Workbooks.Add

    'If Add.Application.Sheets.Count() < 1 Then
    'sheetadd = CType(oneadd.Worksheets.Add, Excel.Worksheet)
    ' Else

    'sheetadd = Add.Worksheets(1)
    'End If
    'sheetadd.Name = "CandidatesCallCenterLocation$"
    'sheetadd.Range("A1").Value = "Row1"
    'oneadd.SaveAs(fexcel)
    'oneadd.Close()
    'oneadd = Nothing
    'DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    'Me.DataGridView.Rows.Add(ACTextBox.Text, MATextBox.Text, AFCTextBox.Text, TextBoxWPH.Text)
    End Sub







' Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
'Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
' Dim cm As New OleDbCommand
'cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Home\Desktop\dss.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""")
'cn.Open()
'With cm
'.Connection = cn
'.CommandText = "update [up$] set [name]=?, [QC_status]=?, [reason]=?, [date]=? WHERE [article_no]=?"
'cm = New OleDbCommand(.CommandText, cn)
'cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ACTextBox.Text)
' cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
'cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox3.Text)
'cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", DateTimePicker1.Text)
'cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox1.Text)
'cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
'MsgBox("UPDATE SUCCESSFUL")
' MyConnection.Close()
'End With
'End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: _"I thought the bottom part worked but apparently, it doesn't"_...the difficulty we've got here is that "Doesn't work" isn't an error message or problem statement. We can't fix "Doesn't work" in code, any more than a mechanic can fix a car that is "not working", without any other information about the problem. How is it not working? What exactly happens when you run the code?

Comment: Also there appear to be two or three different code attempts here, two of which are commented out. I wouldn't recommend the first commented out version as it tries to use COM interop, which is flakey and not really suitable for this purpose anyway. And the second commented-out version appears to be about updating the spreadsheet, not reading from it. So let's focus on the un-commented version...is there a specific problem occurring which you'd like to highlight?

Answer (score 0):

Start a new windows forms project, add a DataGridView and a Button to the form, then:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim filename = "C:\Junk\Junk.xlsx"
  Dim xl As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")       'Late-bound
  Dim b As Object = xl.Workbooks.Open(filename)           'Late-bound
  Dim s As Object = b.Sheets(1) '1-based                     'Late-bound
  Dim values(,) As Object = s.UsedRange.Value2  '1-based
  xl.Quit
  Dim valuesDatatable = New DataTable
  Dim columnCount = values.GetUpperBound(1)
  For col = 1 To columnCount
    valuesDatatable.Columns.Add($"Column{col}")
  Next
  For row = 1 To values.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim o(columnCount - 1) As Object
    For col = 1 To columnCount
      o(col - 1) = values(row, col)
    Next col
    valuesDatatable.Rows.Add(o)
  Next row
  DataGridView1.DataSource = valuesDatatable
End Sub
```

Be aware that Excel starts counting elements from 1, but VB starts counting from 0.

The above uses late-binding, but I would suggest using the [Microsoft Primary Interop Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/office-primary-interop-assemblies?view=vs-2019) to develop (so you have F1 help), then changing to late-binding for deployment (so you aren't tied to a specific version of Excel).